# Primefaces Update Panel (header only)

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I'm using the newest version of primefaces for my JSF 2.0 project.

I am using a panel in which I have some params that might be filled up by the user. Now I'd like to make the panel toggleable and I'd like to write some additional information into the panel header if the panel gets minimized.

Everything works if I use `update="filterPanel"`.

The problem is, that if the whole `filterPanel` gets redrawed, the param values are lost. So what I want is to only update the header of the panel. I checked the HTML source to get the header id, which is: `filterFragment:filterPanel_header`.

But if I try to make `update="filterFragment:filterPanel_header"`, then I get an exception, saying that there is no component with this ID.

Anyone out there who might help me?

```
<p:panel id="filterPanel"
        header="#{cc.attrs.currentPageBean.filterPanelHeaderContent}"
        toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="300" widgetVar="panelFilter"
        styleClass="magnumband magnumbandsize">
        <p:ajax event="toggle"
            listener="#{cc.attrs.currentPageBean.handleToggle}"
            update="filterPanel" />
```

Comment: @Sohel: "JSF 2.0" is **not** code, please don't format software/framework/library names as code.

Comment: Param values are lost? How? Are the values not bound anywhere in the backing bean? What's the scope of your backing bean?